# How to calculate pagination in magritte YAML configs?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

I'm looking to pull data from a REST API that uses a record offset system.  I need to perform basic arithmetic on the returned (`current_offset + item_count`) data to calculate the next offset.

Unfortunately, this API uses a variable page size, so simple offsets won't work.  Nor does it return the next offset to use in the response, just the component values.

However, it appears that there's no way to do even basic arithmetic that I can see.  Am I just missing it?

Comment: we've checked internally and there is no way to do these calculations. We'll open a feature request internally, but I don't know how long it will take.

Comment: I figured out how to do this with paging but it still seems like it would be very useful.